# Risk Events in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Are the identity protections in this article, [Azure Active Directory Identity Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-identityprotection), applicable to Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 1):

**At this time, Azure AD B2C does not support Azure AD Identity Protection.**

You can request this feature ask in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).